# Overlay z-index issue with two div's

Tags: html, css

I have wrapper-top div and shopping cart div, i want to place shopping cart img overlay on wrapper top using z-index.but i am not able to get it , can you any one help me out.

```css
.wrapper-top{
  position:fixed;
  z-index:1000;
}
.shopping-cart{
  position:relative;
  z-index:1001;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-top">
   <a>logo</a>
   <nav></nav>
</div>
<div class="shopping-cart">
    <img src="shopping-cart.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: edited your question with a snippet using your code. seems like the shopping cart image is on top of the `.wrapper-top` . so what's the actual problem ?

Comment: can i give my working test server link, to check that issue.

Comment: But it does that already...

Comment: No, we don't want a link to an external resource, replicate the problem within the question, or else it, and its answers, will be useless for future users

Comment: @Nageswar no. do not share external links. but instead edit you question with all the relevant code required to reproduce the problem you are facing